# Camera is working but I can't see it

Tags: java, android, camera, augmented-reality, vuforia

In app based on Vuforia I want to have some demo also based on Vuforia . So I stop one Vuforia (ARactivity) and use intent to start new activity (Md2activity.class) with something like this:

```
    arActivity.stopAR();

    Intent intent = new Intent(arActivity, Md2activity.class);

    arActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

and .stopAR method:

```
    public void stopAR(){
    try {
        vuforiaAppSession.stopAR();



    } catch (SampleApplicationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    vuforiaAppSession.stopCamera();
    mTextures.clear();
    mTextures = null;

}
```

I can see in consol that it's working fine. Camera recognizes targets etc. But I don't have camera view on the screen. Just ProgressBar.

edit:

public class **Md2activity**  extends Activity implements SampleApplicationControl,
        SampleAppMenuInterface
{
    private static final String LOGTAG = "Md2activity";

```
SampleApplicationSession vuforiaAppSession;

private DataSet mCurrentDataset;
private int mCurrentDatasetSelectionIndex = 0;
private int mStartDatasetsIndex = 0;
private int mDatasetsNumber = 0;
private ArrayList<String> mDatasetStrings = new ArrayList<String>();

private Activity mActivity;
private SampleApplicationControl mSessionControl;


// Our OpenGL view:
private SampleApplicationGLView mGlView;

// Our renderer:
private ImageTargetRendererMd2 mRenderer;

private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

// The textures we will use for rendering:
private Vector<Texture> mTextures;

private boolean mSwitchDatasetAsap = false;
private boolean mFlash = false;
private boolean mContAutofocus = false;
private boolean mExtendedTracking = false;


private View mFlashOptionView;

private RelativeLayout mUILayout;

private SampleAppMenu mSampleAppMenu;

LoadingDialogHandler loadingDialogHandler = new LoadingDialogHandler(this);

// Alert Dialog used to display SDK errors
private AlertDialog mErrorDialog;

private boolean mIsDroidDevice = false;



// Called when the activity first starts or the user navigates back to an
// activity.
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.camera_md2);
    vuforiaAppSession = new SampleApplicationSession(this);


    startLoadingAnimation();
    mDatasetStrings.add("StonesAndChips.xml");
    mDatasetStrings.add("Tarmac.xml");


    vuforiaAppSession
            .initAR(this, ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);


    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new dr.ar.browser.Md2activity.GestureListener());

    // Load any sample specific textures:
    mTextures = new Vector<Texture>();

    mIsDroidDevice = android.os.Build.MODEL.toLowerCase().startsWith(
            "droid");

}

// Process Single Tap event to trigger autofocus
private class GestureListener extends
        GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
{
    // Used to set autofocus one second after a manual focus is triggered
    private final Handler autofocusHandler = new Handler();


    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e)
    {
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e)
    {
        // Generates a Handler to trigger autofocus
        // after 1 second
        autofocusHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                boolean result = CameraDevice.getInstance().setFocusMode(
                        CameraDevice.FOCUS_MODE.FOCUS_MODE_TRIGGERAUTO);

                if (!result)
                    Log.e("SingleTapUp", "Unable to trigger focus");
            }
        }, 1000L);

        return true;
    }
}

// Called when the activity will start interacting with the user.
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "onResume");
    super.onResume();

    // This is needed for some Droid devices to force portrait
    if (mIsDroidDevice)
    {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }

    try
    {
        vuforiaAppSession.resumeAR();
    } catch (SampleApplicationException e)
    {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, e.getString());
    }

    // Resume the GL view:
    if (mGlView != null)
    {
        mGlView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mGlView.onResume();
    }

}


// Callback for configuration changes the activity handles itself
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config)
{
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "onConfigurationChanged");
    super.onConfigurationChanged(config);

    vuforiaAppSession.onConfigurationChanged();
}


// Called when the system is about to start resuming a previous activity.
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "onPause");
    super.onPause();

    if (mGlView != null)
    {
        mGlView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mGlView.onPause();
    }

    // Turn off the flash
    if (mFlashOptionView != null && mFlash)
    {
        // OnCheckedChangeListener is called upon changing the checked state
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
        {
            ((Switch) mFlashOptionView).setChecked(false);
        } else
        {
            ((CheckBox) mFlashOptionView).setChecked(false);
        }
    }

    try
    {
        vuforiaAppSession.pauseAR();
    } catch (SampleApplicationException e)
    {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, e.getString());
    }
}


// The final call you receive before your activity is destroyed.
@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();

    try
    {
        vuforiaAppSession.stopAR();
    } catch (SampleApplicationException e)
    {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, e.getString());
    }

    // Unload texture:
    mTextures.clear();
    mTextures = null;

    System.gc();
}

// Initializes AR application components.
private void initApplicationAR()
{
    // Create OpenGL ES view:
    int depthSize = 16;
    int stencilSize = 0;
    boolean translucent = Vuforia.requiresAlpha();

    mGlView = new SampleApplicationGLView(this);
    mGlView.init(translucent, depthSize, stencilSize);

    mRenderer = new ImageTargetRendererMd2(this, vuforiaAppSession);
    mGlView.setRenderer(mRenderer);

}


private void startLoadingAnimation()
{
    mUILayout = (RelativeLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.camera_overlay,
            null);

    mUILayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mUILayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    // Gets a reference to the loading dialog
    loadingDialogHandler.mLoadingDialogContainer = mUILayout
            .findViewById(R.id.loading_indicator);

    // Shows the loading indicator at start
    loadingDialogHandler
            .sendEmptyMessage(LoadingDialogHandler.SHOW_LOADING_DIALOG);

    // Adds the inflated layout to the view
    addContentView(mUILayout, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

}


// Methods to load and destroy tracking data.
@Override
public boolean doLoadTrackersData()
{
    TrackerManager tManager = TrackerManager.getInstance();
    ObjectTracker objectTracker = (ObjectTracker) tManager
            .getTracker(ObjectTracker.getClassType());
    if (objectTracker == null)
        return false;

    if (mCurrentDataset == null)
        mCurrentDataset = objectTracker.createDataSet();

    if (mCurrentDataset == null)
        return false;

    if (!mCurrentDataset.load(
            mDatasetStrings.get(mCurrentDatasetSelectionIndex),
            STORAGE_TYPE.STORAGE_APPRESOURCE))
        return false;

    if (!objectTracker.activateDataSet(mCurrentDataset))
        return false;

    int numTrackables = mCurrentDataset.getNumTrackables();
    for (int count = 0; count < numTrackables; count++)
    {
        Trackable trackable = mCurrentDataset.getTrackable(count);
        if(isExtendedTrackingActive())
        {
            trackable.startExtendedTracking();
        }

        String name = "Current Dataset : " + trackable.getName();
        trackable.setUserData(name);
        Log.d(LOGTAG, "UserData:Set the following user data "
                + (String) trackable.getUserData());
    }

    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean doUnloadTrackersData()
{
    // Indicate if the trackers were unloaded correctly
    boolean result = true;

    TrackerManager tManager = TrackerManager.getInstance();
    ObjectTracker objectTracker = (ObjectTracker) tManager
            .getTracker(ObjectTracker.getClassType());
    if (objectTracker == null)
        return false;

    if (mCurrentDataset != null && mCurrentDataset.isActive())
    {
        if (objectTracker.getActiveDataSet(0).equals(mCurrentDataset)
                && !objectTracker.deactivateDataSet(mCurrentDataset))
        {
            result = false;
        } else if (!objectTracker.destroyDataSet(mCurrentDataset))
        {
            result = false;
        }

        mCurrentDataset = null;
    }

    return result;
}


@Override
public void onInitARDone(SampleApplicationException exception)
{

    if (exception == null)
    {
        initApplicationAR();

        mRenderer.mIsActive = true;

        // Now add the GL surface view. It is important
        // that the OpenGL ES surface view gets added
        // BEFORE the camera is started and video
        // background is configured.
        addContentView(mGlView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        // Sets the UILayout to be drawn in front of the camera
        mUILayout.bringToFront();

        // Sets the layout background to transparent
        mUILayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        try
        {
            vuforiaAppSession.startAR(CameraDevice.CAMERA_DIRECTION.CAMERA_DIRECTION_DEFAULT);
        } catch (SampleApplicationException e)
        {
            Log.e(LOGTAG, e.getString());
        }

        boolean result = CameraDevice.getInstance().setFocusMode(
                CameraDevice.FOCUS_MODE.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUSAUTO);

        if (result)
            mContAutofocus = true;
        else
            Log.e(LOGTAG, "Unable to enable continuous autofocus");

        mSampleAppMenu = new SampleAppMenu(this, this, "Image Targets",
                mGlView, mUILayout, null);
        setSampleAppMenuSettings();

    } else
    {
        Log.e(LOGTAG, exception.getString());
        showInitializationErrorMessage(exception.getString());
    }
}


// Shows initialization error messages as System dialogs
private void showInitializationErrorMessage(String message)
{
    final String errorMessage = message;
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            if (mErrorDialog != null)
            {
                mErrorDialog.dismiss();
            }


        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onVuforiaUpdate(State state)
{

    if (mSwitchDatasetAsap)
    {
        Log.e("onVuforiaUpdate","成功");
        mSwitchDatasetAsap = false;
        TrackerManager tm = TrackerManager.getInstance();
        ObjectTracker ot = (ObjectTracker) tm.getTracker(ObjectTracker
                .getClassType());
        if (ot == null || mCurrentDataset == null
                || ot.getActiveDataSet(0) == null)
        {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "Failed to swap datasets");
            return;
        }

        doUnloadTrackersData();
        doLoadTrackersData();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean doInitTrackers()
{
    // Indicate if the trackers were initialized correctly
    boolean result = true;

    TrackerManager tManager = TrackerManager.getInstance();
    Tracker tracker;

    // Trying to initialize the image tracker
    tracker = tManager.initTracker(ObjectTracker.getClassType());
    if (tracker == null)
    {
        Log.e(
                LOGTAG,
                "Tracker not initialized. Tracker already initialized or the camera is already started");
        result = false;
    } else
    {
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "Tracker successfully initialized");
    }
    return result;
}


@Override
public boolean doStartTrackers()
{
    // Indicate if the trackers were started correctly
    boolean result = true;

    Tracker objectTracker = TrackerManager.getInstance().getTracker(
            ObjectTracker.getClassType());
    if (objectTracker != null)
        objectTracker.start();

    return result;
}


@Override
public boolean doStopTrackers()
{
    // Indicate if the trackers were stopped correctly
    boolean result = true;

    Tracker objectTracker = TrackerManager.getInstance().getTracker(
            ObjectTracker.getClassType());
    if (objectTracker != null)
        objectTracker.stop();

    return result;
}


@Override
public boolean doDeinitTrackers()
{
    // Indicate if the trackers were deinitialized correctly
    boolean result = true;

    TrackerManager tManager = TrackerManager.getInstance();
    tManager.deinitTracker(ObjectTracker.getClassType());

    return result;
}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    // Process the Gestures
    if (mSampleAppMenu != null && mSampleAppMenu.processEvent(event))
        return true;

    return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}


private boolean isExtendedTrackingActive() {
    return mExtendedTracking;
}

final public static int CMD_BACK = -1;
final public static int CMD_EXTENDED_TRACKING = 1;
final public static int CMD_AUTOFOCUS = 2;
final public static int CMD_FLASH = 3;
final public static int CMD_CAMERA_FRONT = 4;
final public static int CMD_CAMERA_REAR = 5;
final public static int CMD_DATASET_START_INDEX = 6;


// This method sets the menu's settings
private void setSampleAppMenuSettings()
{
    SampleAppMenuGroup group;

    group = mSampleAppMenu.addGroup("", false);
    group.addTextItem(getString(R.string.menu_back), -1);

    group = mSampleAppMenu.addGroup("", true);
    group.addSelectionItem(getString(R.string.menu_extended_tracking),
            CMD_EXTENDED_TRACKING, false);
    group.addSelectionItem(getString(R.string.menu_contAutofocus),
            CMD_AUTOFOCUS, mContAutofocus);
    mFlashOptionView = group.addSelectionItem(
            getString(R.string.menu_flash), CMD_FLASH, false);

    Camera.CameraInfo ci = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    boolean deviceHasFrontCamera = false;
    boolean deviceHasBackCamera = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++)
    {
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, ci);
        if (ci.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
            deviceHasFrontCamera = true;
        else if (ci.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
            deviceHasBackCamera = true;
    }

    if (deviceHasBackCamera && deviceHasFrontCamera)
    {
        group = mSampleAppMenu.addGroup(getString(R.string.menu_camera),
                true);
        group.addRadioItem(getString(R.string.menu_camera_front),
                CMD_CAMERA_FRONT, false);
        group.addRadioItem(getString(R.string.menu_camera_back),
                CMD_CAMERA_REAR, true);
    }

    group = mSampleAppMenu
            .addGroup(getString(R.string.menu_datasets), true);
    mStartDatasetsIndex = CMD_DATASET_START_INDEX;
    mDatasetsNumber = mDatasetStrings.size();

    group.addRadioItem("Stones & Chips", mStartDatasetsIndex, true);
    group.addRadioItem("Tarmac", mStartDatasetsIndex + 1, false);

    mSampleAppMenu.attachMenu();
}


@Override
public boolean menuProcess(int command)
{

    boolean result = true;

    switch (command)
    {
        case CMD_BACK:
            finish();
            break;

        case CMD_FLASH:
            result = CameraDevice.getInstance().setFlashTorchMode(!mFlash);

            if (result)
            {
                mFlash = !mFlash;
            } else
            {
                showToast(getString(mFlash ? R.string.menu_flash_error_off
                        : R.string.menu_flash_error_on));
                Log.e(LOGTAG,
                        getString(mFlash ? R.string.menu_flash_error_off
                                : R.string.menu_flash_error_on));
            }
            break;

        case CMD_AUTOFOCUS:

            if (mContAutofocus)
            {
                result = CameraDevice.getInstance().setFocusMode(
                        CameraDevice.FOCUS_MODE.FOCUS_MODE_NORMAL);

                if (result)
                {
                    mContAutofocus = false;
                } else
                {
                    showToast(getString(R.string.menu_contAutofocus_error_off));
                    Log.e(LOGTAG,
                            getString(R.string.menu_contAutofocus_error_off));
                }
            } else
            {
                result = CameraDevice.getInstance().setFocusMode(
                        CameraDevice.FOCUS_MODE.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUSAUTO);

                if (result)
                {
                    mContAutofocus = true;
                } else
                {
                    showToast(getString(R.string.menu_contAutofocus_error_on));
                    Log.e(LOGTAG,
                            getString(R.string.menu_contAutofocus_error_on));
                }
            }

            break;

        case CMD_CAMERA_FRONT:
        case CMD_CAMERA_REAR:

            // Turn off the flash
            if (mFlashOptionView != null && mFlash)
            {
                // OnCheckedChangeListener is called upon changing the checked state
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
                {
                    ((Switch) mFlashOptionView).setChecked(false);
                } else
                {
                    ((CheckBox) mFlashOptionView).setChecked(false);
                }
            }

            vuforiaAppSession.stopCamera();

            try
            {
                vuforiaAppSession
                        .startAR(command == CMD_CAMERA_FRONT ? CameraDevice.CAMERA_DIRECTION.CAMERA_DIRECTION_FRONT
                                : CameraDevice.CAMERA_DIRECTION.CAMERA_DIRECTION_BACK);
            } catch (SampleApplicationException e)
            {
                showToast(e.getString());
                Log.e(LOGTAG, e.getString());
                result = false;
            }
            doStartTrackers();
            break;

        case CMD_EXTENDED_TRACKING:
            for (int tIdx = 0; tIdx < mCurrentDataset.getNumTrackables(); tIdx++)
            {
                Trackable trackable = mCurrentDataset.getTrackable(tIdx);

                if (!mExtendedTracking)
                {
                    if (!trackable.startExtendedTracking())
                    {
                        Log.e(LOGTAG,
                                "Failed to start extended tracking target");
                        result = false;
                    } else
                    {
                        Log.d(LOGTAG,
                                "Successfully started extended tracking target");
                    }
                } else
                {
                    if (!trackable.stopExtendedTracking())
                    {
                        Log.e(LOGTAG,
                                "Failed to stop extended tracking target");
                        result = false;
                    } else
                    {
                        Log.d(LOGTAG,
                                "Successfully started extended tracking target");
                    }
                }
            }

            if (result)
                mExtendedTracking = !mExtendedTracking;

            break;

        default:
            if (command >= mStartDatasetsIndex
                    && command < mStartDatasetsIndex + mDatasetsNumber)
            {
                mSwitchDatasetAsap = true;
                mCurrentDatasetSelectionIndex = command
                        - mStartDatasetsIndex;
            }
            break;
    }

    return result;
}


private void showToast(String text)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Comment: Many things can go wrong - there are not enough details here. If you launch Md2activity as the main activity, does it work properly?  are you managing your views order properly (making sure main view is visible and at the front)

Comment: yes, if I launch md2activity as the main activity it's fine. I'm not sure about 2nd question how can I check it.?

Comment: setContentView is not working.

Comment: How do you know it's not working? You should add the code for Md2activity here.

Comment: I added Md2activity. I still have only view from previous activity and progress bar.

Comment: I'm not sure, but would suggest you look at these two directions: 1. startActivity with options,  2. overriding onNewIntent

Comment: The question was incorrectly tagged. Please pay attention to the tag wikis. [tag:ar] does not mean [tag:augmented-reality]